# Django-allauth - URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

I'm trying to set Facebook login and registration on my web page (localhost for now).

1. Installed allauth
2. Set settings.py
3. Created an facebook app 
   [image]

And now, when I click on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/` facebook href, it returns this alert:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

According to sites, I've set domain name (in Django-admin Sites) to

```
localhost
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Call your app via localhost instead of using the IP address …?